# How do I resolve this plot 'subscript OOB' error?

Tags: r, plot

I'm comparing values within matrix `genes` by column, so the x-axis corresponds to each matrix column, which the y-values correspond to different values. The plot function works but I get a "Subscript out of bounds error". I need to create plots for hundreds of matrices so I would like to avoid hard-coding #s in, but I was wondering whether someone could identify what I'm overlooking in that `for` loop.
Thank you.

```
genes <- matrix(c(1,2,3, 11,12,13, 43,45,56, 54,23,65), nrow = 2, ncol = 6, byrow =  TRUE, dimnames = list(c("row1", "row2"), c("C.1", "C.2", "C.3", "C.4", "C.5", "C.6"))) 
colors <- colors()[c(130, 8, 461, 47, 84, 53, 554, 418, 640, 275, 143, 258, 345,123, 35,86, 92,29,63,84)]

dev.off()
plot(c(1,ncol(genes)),range(genes),type='n',xlab="",ylab="",axes=F)
axis(side=1,at=c(1:ncol(genes),labels=colnames(genes),cex.axis=0.8,las=2)
axis(side=2)
for(i in 1:ncol(genes)) {
  ycoord <- as.numeric(genes[i,])
  lines(c(1:ncol(genes)),ycoord,col=colors[i],lwd=2)
}
legend("topright", legend=rownames(genes), fill=colors, bg="white", cex = .8, ncol=1)
```

Comment: I think you want `for (i in 1:nrow(genes))...`, no?? That fixed it for me.

Comment: Also, why is this tagged `ggplot`???

Comment: @jlhoward thanks. Good to have an extra pair of eyes. Not sure why ggplot2 was tagged; I'll remove it.